# Passing android Camera object from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-camera

In an android flashlight app , I am using the camera in 1st activity :

```
    Camera camera;
    //later in the code..
    camera = Camera.open();
```

and the 2nd activity of the flashlight , Is a strobe light which also uses the camera:

```
    Camera cam;
    cam = Camera.open();
```

The strobe light cannot be used since the camera is in use by the previous activity.I want to pass the camera in the 1st activity to the 2nd activity to have only 1 camera object in the app.

I tried to implement Serializable but it cannot pass camera object

Any idea how to do it ? Or is there any better way

Comment: You need to release camera first before you open it again. It doesn't matter if it's in another activity or not.

Comment: have done so in addition to some if statements for current state of flash, problem solved . No crashes now :)

Answer (score 0):

Singleton pattern will be ok for it:

```
public class StaticCamera{
private StaticCamera instance;
public static synchronized StaticCamera getInstance(){

if(instance == null){
instance = new StaticCamera();
}
return instance;
}
private Camera mCamera;
private StaticCamera(){
mCamera = Camera.open();
}

}
```

Add the getter method for mCamera field and you got all you need just call `StaticCamera.getInstance().getCamera()`

Quite important thing - you should write also release method like:

```
public static void dispose(){
instance == null;
}
```

just to allow garbage collector to collect the object if no longer needed (of course you need to call it manually).

**Update**

I showed how to pass object reference from one to other activity. Your problem is that you're trying to turn on and off the light between activities. Best option for do it if it's only the flash light is to have only one Activity and use fragments for switching UI.

Comment: Tried it , didn't work , camera is still considered in use , in the 2nd activity.

Comment: I released the camera in 1st activity and created another camera object in 2nd activity.Then onResume of 1st activity I opened the 1st camera again , and everything is working ok.But I am afraid to have memory issues on low end devices when I publish it ?

Comment: Camera itself is implemented as singleton, so there is no point creating another singleton.